# Fail to build project due to mobile_scanner and firebase_auth dependency conflicts

Tags: flutter

After recent updates i fail to build my flutter project.

There seems to  be a conflict between the mobile_scanner package and firebase_auth.

Anyone that knows how to solve this?

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 10.0.0) was resolved to 10.0.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAuth (~> 10.0.0) was resolved to 10.0.0, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 2.1)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.7.0, which depends on
          MLKitVision (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
            GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
€
```

Answer (score 1):

It was reported on IssueTracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254418199#comment22

```
Currently the next release is planned at the end of Q4.
```

Comment: I see that it has not been resolved yet.